# N number of Collection View cells - autoresize to fir all cells in screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I need to fit my collection view cells inside the iphone screen bounds always.

It should work like :

- If one cell, it should fill entire screen
- If two cells, first cell should fill the first half and second should fill second half
- if three cells, screen should divide in 4 equal cells and 4th cell placeholder should be empty. In case of 4th cell, it should fill the empty space.
- If five/six cells, there should be three rows of two cells each.

I had a logic but with some hack I managed to support only 6 cells, after that it doesn't work.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        var horizontalTiles = 1
        var verticalTiles = 1
        
        var targetWidth = collectionView.frame.width
        var targetHeight = collectionView.frame.height - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        
        horizontalTiles = horizontalTiles+(self.contactsArray.count/3)
        verticalTiles = verticalTiles+(self.contactsArray.count/2)
        
        if self.contactsArray.count%4 == 0 || self.contactsArray.count%6 == 0 {
            return lastCellSize
        }
        
        targetWidth = targetWidth / CGFloat(horizontalTiles)
        targetHeight = targetHeight / CGFloat(verticalTiles)
        
        let size = CGSize(width: targetWidth, height: targetHeight)
        
        lastCellSize = size
        
        return size
    }
```

If there is any better way or by using flow layout it would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: What you’re describing is not a simple collection view. A collection view has just one layout. The layout does not know how many cells there are. You would need a different custom layout each time the number of cells changes.

Comment: This is an odd UX, and not something collection views are designed to handle. As Matt says, you would have to change the UICollectionViewLayout every time the number of cell changes. There are methods to change the collection view's layout, but you may be in uncharted territory and have to work this out on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the animations aside... you could get the sizes with some clever math/logic (your question asks specifically about sizing).

**Some observations/assumptions:**

- All cells are the same size, so we can return one size
- Number of rows/columns alternate incrementing
- Rows increment before columns
- Size remains the same until all columns are filled in the last row

Given this...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let numItems = self.contactsArray.count

    let targetWidth = collectionView.frame.width
    let targetHeight = collectionView.frame.height - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

    if numItems == 1 {
        return CGSize(width: targetWidth, height: targetHeight)
    }
    
    // Below logic only works for numItems > 1, so we check for that ^

    var numRows = 1
    var numColumns = 1

    for index in 1...(numItems-1) {
        if index % numColumns == 0 {
            if numColumns == numRows {
                numRows += 1
            } else {
                numColumns += 1
            }
        }
    }

    return CGSize(width: targetWidth / numColumns, height: targetHeight / numRows)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not glued to using a collection view, here's another approach.

Think in terms of rows and columns. The number of rows will be the ceil of the square root of total items, and the number of columns will be the ceil of total items divided by number of rows.

You can then easily calculate the "tile" dimensions.

[image]

Example code:

```
class ArrangeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // Add a view button
    let addButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        return v
    }()
    
    // Remove a view button
    let remButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.setTitle("Remove", for: [])
        return v
    }()
    
    // horizontal stackview to hold the buttons
    let btnsStack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fillEqually
        v.spacing = 20
        return v
    }()
    
    // view to hold the added views
    let tilesContainerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        v.clipsToBounds = true
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        // button properties
        [addButton, remButton].forEach { b in
            b.backgroundColor = .yellow
            b.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
            b.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        }
        
        // add the buttons to the stack view
        btnsStack.addArrangedSubview(addButton)
        btnsStack.addArrangedSubview(remButton)
        
        // add buttons stack to the view
        view.addSubview(btnsStack)
        
        // add border container to the view
        view.addSubview(tilesContainerView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain buttons stack Top / Leading / Trailing with a little "padding"
            btnsStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            btnsStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btnsStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            // buttons height to 40-pts (just for asthetics)
            btnsStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
            
            // constrain border container
            // 20-pts below buttons
            tilesContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnsStack.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            // 20-pts from view bottom
            tilesContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            // 20-pts Leading and Trailing
            tilesContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            tilesContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
        // add actions for the Add and Delete buttons
        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        remButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(remTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        }) { [unowned self] _ in
            self.arrangeViews()
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func addTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        
        // instantiate a new custom view and add it to
        // the inner container view
        let v = MyArrangeView()
        tilesContainerView.addSubview(v)
        v.theLabel.text = "\(tilesContainerView.subviews.count)"
        
        // update the arrangement
        arrangeViews()
        
    }
    
    @objc func remTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        
        // if inner container has at least one custom view
        if let v = tilesContainerView.subviews.last {
            
            // remove it
            v.removeFromSuperview()
            
            // update the arrangement
            arrangeViews()
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func arrangeViews() -> Void {
        
        // make sure there is at least 1 subview to arrange
        guard tilesContainerView.subviews.count > 0 else { return }
        
        // init local vars to use
        // Note: making them all CGFLoats makes it easier to use in expressions - avoids a lot of casting CGFloat(var)
        
        var numCols: CGFloat = 0
        var numRows: CGFloat = 0
        
        var w: CGFloat = 0
        var h: CGFloat = 0
        
        // this is the frame we need to fit inside
        let containerWidth: CGFloat = tilesContainerView.frame.size.width
        let containerHeight: CGFloat = tilesContainerView.frame.size.height
        
        // number of views to arrange
        let numTiles: CGFloat = CGFloat(tilesContainerView.subviews.count)
        
        // get the ceil of the square root of number of tiles
        //  that's the number of rows
        numRows = CGFloat(ceil(sqrt(numTiles)))
        
        // get the ceil of the number of tiles divided by number of rows
        //  that's the number of columns
        numCols = CGFloat(ceil(numTiles / numRows))

        // size of each tile
        w = containerWidth / numCols
        h = containerHeight / numRows
        
        var x: CGFloat = 0.0
        var y: CGFloat = 0.0
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            
            // loop through, doing the actual layout (setting each item's frame)
            self.tilesContainerView.subviews.forEach { v in
                
                v.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
                x += w
                if x + w > containerWidth + 1 {
                    x = 0.0
                    y += h
                }
                
            }
            
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

    }
    
}


// simple bordered custom view with a label in a "content container"
class MyArrangeView: UIView {
    
    // this will hold the "content" of the custom view
    // for this example, it just holds a label
    let theContentView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        return v
    }()
    
    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        self.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        // add the label to the content view
        theContentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        
        // add the content view to self
        addSubview(theContentView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain the label to all 4 sides of the content view
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContentView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain the content view to all 4 sides of self with 5-pts "padding"
            theContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            theContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -5.0),
            theContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            theContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -5.0),
            
        ])
        
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray.cgColor
    }
    
}
```

And, rotated...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However using collectionview is necessary here.